# Why can't I use @WebServiceProvider on a @Stateless EJB?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

If I try to put the `@WebServiceProvider` annotation on to a Stateless Session Bean, I get weird error messages.

I did find one site on the internet, where it states, that you cannot build a Provider with an EJB..., but the site was nothing official...

I can't find anything about that in the spec... or I missed something.

Can or can't I use something like this:

```
@ServiceMode(Service.Mode.PAYLOAD)
@WebServiceProvider(portName = "Port", targetNamespace = "http://www.example.org", serviceName = "Service", wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/Service.wsdl")
@Stateless
public class ServiceProvider implements Provider<Source> {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Imagine that you would have a dog, and then you say "no, this dog is also a car". When the dog has problems, do you take it to the vet or to the garage? Or both? You get into conflict problems when you have different managing systems having to operate on the same entity, its far better to just shove the dog into a car and possibly put other things in the car too.

Comment: Funny,... but in the end it does not answer the question... For example, I can definitely tell my EJB it is a @WebService, so where is the difference, and shouldn't it tell me somewhere (like in the spec or something)?

Comment: But a WebService is an entirely different thing with an entirely different purpose than a WebServiceProvider.